# Cannot find System.Runtime assembly while initializing XAML Previewer

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin-previewer

An error occurs when I'm trying to load *XAML Previewer* for *Xamarin.Forms*.

Cannot find `System.Runtime` assembly (see screenshot) while initializing renderer.

Target framework: `.Net Standart 2.0`.
Installed assemblies: `NetStandart.Library 2.0.3`, `Xamarin.Forms 4.0.0.425677`.

XAML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinLab"
             x:Class="XamarinLab.MainPage"
             Title="Authorization">

    <ScrollView>
        <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="SkyBlue">
            <Frame AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, -1, -1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" HasShadow="True" CornerRadius="15">
                <StackLayout WidthRequest="150">
                    <Entry x:Name="LoginEntry" Placeholder="login"/>
                    <Entry x:Name="PasswordEntry" Placeholder="password" IsPassword="True"/>
                    <Button Text="Sign In" Clicked="OnLoginButtonClicked" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                    <Button Text="Sign Up" Clicked="OnRegisterButtonClicked" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                </StackLayout>

            </Frame>

            <ActivityIndicator x:Name="Loading" Margin="5" Color="White" IsRunning="False" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,0,100,40" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"/>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

The error:

[image: The error screenshot]

Comment: This isn't an answer,  but I've found the xaml previewer to be unstable  I use gorilla player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you have some issue when you want to use xaml previewer.

From [XAML Previewer for Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/?pivots=windows), you can check the following steps:

**XAML Previewer isn't showing or shows an error**

It can take some time for the Previewer to start up - you'll see "Initializing Render" until it's ready.

Try closing and reopening the XAML file.

Ensure that your App class has a parameterless constructor.

Check your Xamarin.Forms version - it has to be at least Xamarin.Forms 3.6. You can update to the latest Xamarin.Forms version through NuGet.

Check your JDK installation - previewing Android requires at least JDK 8.

Try wrapping any initialized classes in the page's C# code behind in if (!DesignMode.IsDesignModeEnabled).

You said that your xamarin.forms version is 4.0.0.425677, can you uninstall and install other version( for example 3.6) to try again